# XenServer VM GUI on host

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, host, xen

I have an XenServer setup with multiple VM's running on it. I want to be able to interact with one of those VM's from the XenServer console. For example, if I have a windows VM I would like to interact with it from the XenServer host console all while the other VM's are running. Is that possible?

This is my first question and hopefully I posted it right. Sorry if I did something wrong. I searched for an answer but I was unable to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

By interact with it, do you mean login to it?  If so, you're at the wrong place.  You should login to your VMs from the XenCenter app, which you'll install on your windows machine by going to http://ipOfYourZenserver (ie. http://192.168.1.75 or whatever).

The only thing you might be able to do from you Xenserver is ssh to one of the machines running.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install XenCenter from http://yourXenServerIp/
2. Connect to your XenServer, via Server -> Add
3. Click the VM in question in the left tree
4. On the right pane click the Console tab, which should display the output from your VM. If it's running and Windows has started you should see the Windows GUI.

Ideally you should install XenTools on your VM's to improve performance (this includes better console interaction).

We've found it best to enable remote desktop on our Windows VM's and connect using the Windows RDP client (Start -> Run -> mstsc).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to interact with VMs that are in XenServer, but you need XenCenter app to do that (make sure to get a compatible version of XenCenter eg if you are using XenServer 7 you must use XenCenter 7 or 8 etc).

After installing XenServer, connect it to your XenCenter and then all the VMs will appear in a list at the left side. Then, you can select any VM you want and from the "console" tab you can have interact in it like any other hypervisor (eg virtualbox).

If this isn't clear enough let me know.